# Am I stuck with Notepad++?

Tags: php, sql-server, visual-studio, ide, dreamweaver

Does anyone know of an IDE that will set a connection to MS SQL from a PHP site?

Dreamweaver will not connect to MS SQL like Visual Studio does, but Visual Studio will not debug PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by 'set a connection to MSSQL'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need some IDE sugestions for PHP and SQL Server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205634/i-need-some-ide-sugestions-for-php-and-sql-server-2012)

Comment: Visual Basic allows you to connect to a MS SQL database in such a way that you can view and import database objects and stored procedures straight into your code from within the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any IDE can be used to  use MSSQL with PHP, the IDE doesn't actually do anything in relation to the database. Your PHP interpretor only sees PHP text files and executes them when needed, and manages everything that is database related.

If you are looking for a good IDE, PHPStorm is a very good choice :

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: PHPStorm has to be one of my favorite IDE editors, using it on a free personal plan as I contacted jetbrains. I haven't looked back

Comment: Yeah, JetBrains' IDEs are always professional and well done. For PHP, Zend Studio is decent as well but I still prefer PHPStorm.

Comment: Thanks I'll give those a try. I just was hoping there was something out there that handled a lot of the connection string code and gave drag and drop access to stored procedures in MSSQL.

Comment: @MatthewKennedy It might be a little bit complicated and not straight forward to connect the IDE to a database. I had some trouble with that, but the manual is explanatory